# How do I assign negative positioning in percentage for elements in css?

Tags: css, positioning

I have a panel which has top:-138px; I want to give this in %, i tried giving negative percentage but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this as long as its parent element has a defined height, whether in pixels or percentage.  If you play around with this fiddle, you'll notice that the inner element's `top` attribute is only respected if you give the container an explicitly-definied `height`.

http://jsfiddle.net/KcWSr/

Comment: Thanks, my only problem is that my css is getting screwed for different screen sizes, is there anyway to keep it constant across all browser sizes?

Comment: Generally, when you design using percentages, it's because you *want* the design to flex for different screen sizes.  If that's not what you want, you should consider using fixed dimensions, or a combination of the two.

Comment: I agree, before, I use some media queries and pixel as basis for designing in different screen sizes, only to find out that I will be doing a lot more work. Percentage is beneficial when you want your design to be flexible across multiple screen sizes, as @MattHowell pointed out..